# A word for "to proceed inwards from the outside", like "bottom-up"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

"Bottom-up" means to proceed upwards from the bottom.

"Top-down" means to proceed downwards from the top.

Then is there a hyphenated word meaning to proceed inwards from the outside? "Outside-in" sounds like it means the outside is **turned** inwards like how we can turn a glove outside-in, so I'm not sure if it's the correct word.

Comment: As an aside, I would say that a glove can be turned *inside-out*, not *outside-in* - the meaning is the same, but I think the term *inside-out* is much more common amongst native English speakers.

Comment: "*“to proceed inwards from the outside”,*" indicates you want a verb. That would be "to enter." -- ""*Bottom-up" means to proceed upwards from the bottom. "Top-down" means to proceed downwards from the top.*" I'm not sure this is true. Do you have examples? (I agree with *nnnnnn* - outside-in is not idiomatic)

Comment: Is it centripetal?

Comment: The phrase would be 'to proceed inwards'. The meaning of  'from the outside' would be implicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sound perfectly fine to me:

> The mortician examined the corpse from top to bottom and from the **outside in**.
>   The lab technician conducted an **outside-in** examination of the sample.

In both cases, I'm able to assume that something started externally and finished internally.

In fact, *outside in* is used so infrequently, that nobody, especially in the context of the example sentences, would be likely to confuse it with something else.

Incidentally, we turn gloves (and other things) [*inside out*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inside%20out), never *outside in*.

---

Similarly, with additional context, the assertion that *bottom up* means "to proceed upwards from the bottom" is not always the case:

> He turned the glass *bottom[s] up*. [The bottom and top reversed positions.]

It's when you don't use the word *turn* that the directional phrase takes on the meaning originally ascribed to it:

> The company had a *bottom-up* hierarchy. [Change started at the bottom and went upward.]

The same phrase can be used, but have a different meaning depending on context.

Comment: The trouble is that a dictionary definition (in a decent dictionary; we don't seem to be bothering providing helpful references) for 'outside-in' _**is**_ "an alternative for 'inside-out' >>. A person not having met the term before but aware that English doesn't always behave predictably might look it up.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *Outside in* is not an alternative for *inside out* in the context of reversing external and internal pieces. It's erroneous to discount the phrase (in the question) on the basis that there would be common confusion over it and its logical reverse. (It's also not something that even appears in Merriam-Webster or Oxford as a distinct entry—it's not possible to provide a reference to something that doesn't exist. And, so, there is no sense of a common use at all; there isn't one.)

Comment: You've forced me to add a reference. << [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Outside+In) ... 19. **outside in** another term for inside out. >> It's standard practice on ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It would be better to provide a link directly to the [Collins entry](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/outside-in) entry, rather than to The Free Dictionary. Looking at Collins, the grammar being used is not the same as *turning* something inside out. In fact, "I parked outside in full view," and others like it, is a very poor demonstration (not a demonstration at all) of its equivalence to the sense of *inside out* you're trying to debate.

Comment: If you check _carefully_, you will see that Collins fails at the level of providing correct examples. It claims that 'outside in' and 'inside out' are synonymous. The 'examples' are false positives the editors have failed to check. In none of them could 'inside out' be used. Look at correct example sentences for 'inside out' [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/inside-out). Here's a legit example: 'Cortical development: Binocular plasticity turned outside-in.' [[US National Library of Medicine NIH](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10801431)]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Exactly so. That's why Collins doesn't work. The last example is interesting, but I'd again say that it's not talking about reversing the physical (literal) position of anything. Instead, it's using it in the sense that I already did in my answer—which doesn't argue against using it where that sense is made clear, and doesn't cause confusion. (It's essentially saying the same thing as "turning it on its head"; any number of expressions could be used.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth To put this simply, the only time when *outside in* would cause confusion, would be if it were describing the same literal (not figurative) activity of turning something *inside out*; i.e., where items on the exterior actually reverse themselves with the items on the interior. But, as far as I can tell, that can't be found—because we only use *inside out* for describing such a thing. Therefore, there is no confusion, and there is no reason to avoid the phrase. *Outside in* is the phrase used to describe proceeding inwards—and without confusion.

Comment: It's a pity that 'outside in' has a dictionary defining it as 'inside out' and you don't cite one licensing the meaning 'from the outside to the inside'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What you keep citing as a dictionary definition is not in the sense described. It clearly does *not* mean the same thing as *inside out* in the sense of two things physically (literally) reversing position. My sense is based on the actual definitions of the two distinct words *inside* and *out*. There is no dictionary definition for *outside in* that covers the sense under discussion here. You seem hung up on this and have missed the answer to the question itself altogether, arguing about something that isn't actually relevant.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If you really think that *outside in* can be used in common discourse in the literal sense of "the outside turned inwards," you have yet to show any evidence of that.

Comment: I've provided a dictionary definition, from a respected dictionary, stating that 'outside in' is used in the same sense as 'inside out'. You, in an 'answer', have not provided one stating that 'outside in' is used in the same sense as 'centripetally'.

Comment: [Here {Google Books}](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=jLe8BQAAQBAJ&pg=PT55&lpg=PT55&dq=%22jacket+outside+in+and%22&source=bl&ots=qxvY-zNAHo&sig=ACfU3U3qOCNvwGu31Obl9EToUXZNh06FPw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwje_rXLtPToAhVKiFwKHe2pDA8Q6AEwCnoECAUQKA#v=onepage&q=%22jacket%20outside%20in%20and%22&f=false) is an example from a work of [Duncan Williamson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duncan_Williamson): 'I turned the jacket outside in and left it down on the banking.'

Comment: A [Jane Hinckley, on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-inside-out-and-outside-in), says 'There is really no difference. If a piece of clothing is hung wrong, the most common way to describe it is “inside out.” “Outside in” is a cute synonym. “This shirt is stained so I’m wearing it outside in. You can’t see the stain.” ' Really convincing evidence? Perhaps not. _But way better than providing no evidence._